# How to reset simulated_data_sharing_consumer?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-sharing

Snowflake documentation recommends setting `simulated_data_sharing_consumer` parameter at a session level for testing data shares, in a manner similar to this:

```
-- For example, for a consumer account named xy12345:
alter session set simulated_data_sharing_consumer = xy12345;
```

Is it possible to reset this parameter, without ending the session? If so, how? I was not able to find specific instruction in Snowflake documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[ALTER SESSION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-session.html):

> UNSET
>
> Specifies one (or more) parameters to unset for the session, which resets them to the defaults.

Thus:

```
ALTER SESSION UNSET simulated_data_sharing_consumer;
```